# Mounting Pullup bar above door. Inner wall studs do not extend above door

Tags: walls, framing, mounting, studs

I want to mount a pullup bar (rouge jammer) above a regular 30 inch wide door in my detached garage.

I ran my studfinder above the door inside and could not find a stud. Upon opening up the drywall, I can see interior wall of the garage (studs to which the door drame is secured) stops 1.5inches above the door. So there are no studs to mount to above the door height, at any place in the garage. 4.5 inches behind the drywall, there is a second wall covered by plywood that extends all the way up. I think this outerwall has studs and must be load bearing for the roof.

I was thinking I'd just cut out the drywall above the door and use lag screws to attach 2x6s to the outer wall so I have a solid platform to mount to.

So 2 questions;

1. Why does my inner wall just have studs that disappear
2. Is there a better way to add support and surface area I can mount to?

[image: poor drawing]

[image: View inside wall]

Comment: Most door/window openings have a king stud going to the top plate and a jack stud to hold the door/window header above the door/window.  Maybe you missed the king stud?

Comment: The top plate for the inner wall is at the bottom of the photo there. The king stud the door is attached to ends below this. I agree it should run all the way up, and I was expecting to see a big chunk of wood to mount to there. The rest of the outer wall and studs that run all the way up have to be behind that plywood to the right, so i sort of need to bridge from that plywood (right) to the inner drywall (left) to create a mounting surface

Comment: Maybe the constructor wanted an unobstructed path for some sort of utilities, but abandoned the idea? With stud grade 2x4s commonly available at only around 8 ft long, I can't imagine saving a buck on construction material by doing that. "How did they save a buck" is usually my first heuristic for understanding goofy stuff like this. The studs aren't exactly 8 ft long, are they?

Comment: So if I look to the other side on this hole, you can see some electrical run. But it looks like it runs through a hole in that top plate (bottom of the photo) so not super unobstructed. I guess that still could be the case that they abandoned the idea. 

I'll measure the studs later and let you know on the 8ft thing. I guess if thats the case, the real "fix" would be to put in new taller studs and raise that top plate? I'd love to mount more stuff up high as I build out the home gym and even get a wall mounted rig in there. Now all sounding like a lot of work..

Comment: What about the "second wall covered by plywood that goes all of the way up." That wall has plenty of strength it sounds like. If there are fasteners from the other side of this plywood that then penetrate a good 1-1/2" into the weak wall, then the weak wall is still borrowing full strength from the back wall. If it's toe nailed from the garage side and into the plywood, however, then I would share your caution about the existing wall's strength. Can you sneak a putty knife or something between the stud and plywood to check for fastener frequency?

Comment: @popham I will give that a shot and see what I learn.

Comment: If it's no good, then you can get some lag screws (or deck ledger fasteners), use a paddle bit or Forstner bit to counter sink for the heads, and fasten through the low top plate and into the back wall's studs. You might take a second look into that upper chamber to be sure that there are 2 or 3 face nails per stud fastening them to the top plate.

Comment: You say this wall is *in* your garage, which tells me it's not between garage and house, or garage and exterior.  Is that correct—what does this wall separate?

Comment: @Huesmann its a standalone structure separate from the house. It is the garage wall itself, not a separate wall within the garage. Laziness with my words.

Comment: @DeepDIYingValue so it's an exterior door of a detached garage?